# How to Move as well as clear data in spreadsheets

Tags: google-apps-script

I want to move the data in spreadsheet 1 to another spreadsheet but, after the data is moved, spreadsheet 1 is automatically empty but without removing the buttom.

like this my project : https://prnt.sc/xT6EHL1zWFxJ
(sorry I can't insert my project image)

and

there is an error in my script. here's the notification :

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'copyTo')
```

this my script :

```
function moveSheet() {
  var sheetToMove = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var destinationSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1hv-y79md66vHRBzEFB_Ox74ulk8Iyf8ykUl06O3s1Rg");
  sheetToMove.copyTo(destinationSpreadsheet);
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().deleteSheet(sheetToMove);
}
```

I want to move my data on sheet but without removing the buttom. I've tried this and that in order to achieve such and such but I'm struggling with this and that :-(

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the sheet `Sheet1` doesn't exist in the parent sheet. You may want to put a check in your code.

```
function moveSheet() {
  const parent = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheetToMove = parent.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  if (sheetToMove) {
    const destinationSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("123....");
    sheetToMove.copyTo(destinationSpreadsheet);
    parent.deleteSheet(sheetToMove);
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  }
}
```

Comment: If you think the answer solved your problem, you may consider accepting it.

Comment: yes sir, your script really helped my project, but after that there was another problem, where the buttons on the sheet moved too